# render json array in PUG

Tags: json, pug

I have a JSON Object with an array in it. I want to render the array values in a loop of my PUG Template.

```
p= products.PGR[0].$.name
  each pro in products.PRG
    div= pro.$.name
```

The first line printet out the value name correctly, but when I put this into a each loop the following error is displayed:

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused when you aren't passing a variable properly into your each operator.

This would happen because you've flipped `PGR` around to `PRG`, which would be an empty JavaScript object at runtime with no length.